# How to downgrade to 1.3.0

Tags: github, windows-xp, github-for-windows

Im using win xp and got upgraded to 1.3.1 which is not xp compatabile so login keeps failing.

https://windows.github.com/release-notes.html

How to  downgrade to 1.3.0?

Thanks

Comment: Ironically enough, for a revision-control system, they don’t seem to have old versions of their own software. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Hahahahahah @Synetech that is just a hilarious thought, I didn't think of it like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have no real solution here. As they don't provide older version binaries for *GitHub for Windows*, you cannot install it unless you have an installation file.

GitHub recently merged *GitHub for Windows* and *GitHub for Mac* into one application: *GitHub Desktop* and it requires **Windows 7 or later**:

> [image]
>
> https://desktop.github.com/

In short, you cannot use any official desktop app from GitHub since they don't support XP anymore.

As alternative, you can use GitHub in your browser, push commits from your command line or a desktop client that supports XP.